# Locust test is spawning far more users than it is asked to

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, load-testing, locust

I'm running locust load tests on a Google Kubernetes cluster. When I specify a smaller number of users, it works as documented. At a certain point when I increase user counts, it spawns vastly more users than I asked it to and stays around that number. Neither my nodes nor the target system are shown as being overloaded on resources. Concrete examples (with all other configuration details identical:

Requested: 10,000 users, actual: 10,000

Requested: 20,000 users, actual: 20,000

Requested: 40,000 users, actual: varies from 60,000-120,000

If it was below the requested users, I could understand (system overwhelmed: can't spawn enough). If it occasionally went a little above requested users, I could understand (communication latency could result in occasional over-spawning). but going multiples higher and maintaining that leaves me baffled. Anyone have insight into this?

Comment: Could you please let me know if you are changing the spawn rate while increasing users ? Also, could you please comment if there was any impact on the latencies of the target systems ?

Comment: Are you requests returning any errors?

Comment: chaitanya: This is with a consistent spawn rate across all tests (100 in every case here). The latencies are generally higher when it gives me more users than I asked for.

Solowalker: About 1-2% of requests give errors when the issue is reproing. Fewer (though not zero) in the stable scenarios.

Comment: Is your number of workers increasing at the same time?

Comment: My worker count goes quickly up to however many pods I set up, then stops. I've never seen it go over the number specified.

Comment: Have you checked logs? The master should log how many users it's telling each worker to spawn. Workers should also log when they get spawn events.

Comment: Which specific logs are you referring to? I've looked at lots of logs for lots of information. Also, what details would be relevant? If we see that a worker is being told to spawn an unreasonable number of users, that doesn't actually tell us anything we don't already know.

Comment: Locust logs. There could be other information around the spawn event that could shed light on the problem. Perhaps the workers are always getting the correct spawn counts but then something else happens. Perhaps some workers are overwhelmed at the time and not responding so the master sends higher spawn counts to the remaining workers but then doesn't rebalance when the other workers check in again. Or perhaps the increased error rate is causing more users than you'd expect as new users replace errored ones. Lots of options.

Comment: Nothing I've been able to find in the logs that would have any hint as to the behavior. Looked both in the master's log and several worker logs (very little in those ones, but I wanted to check in case).